# Gradient along the surface of a helical spiral

Tags: modifiers, screw-modifier

I want to create a gradient that spirals along with the helical structure like in the figure attached. However I cannot seem to get the gradient curving the right way. I have tried turning several knobs to no avail as shown in the screenshot. Any assistance will be appreciated.

[image: Reference image]

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1G0s.png]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use object coordinates (and considering the object origin is at the center), you can't do it with a mapping alone as it will not allow to start at the inner radius of the helicoid in all directions.

Instead you can:

Keep only X and Z as the helicoid is along Y.

Get the length, which goes from the inner radius to the outer radius.

Remap the length from min (the inner radius) and from max (the outer radius) to 0 and 1.

[image]

---

If you've made the shape with a screw modifier, use UV stretch:

[image]

And keep only the Y value from the UV coordinates:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the solid advice. This does the trick magnificently

Answer (score 3):

You can use the UV of the object: make one orthogonal face of your spiral object active (or in the *UV Editor* make one face orthogonal and make it active) and *Unwrap > Follow Active Quads*:

[image]

In the *Texture Coordinate* node choose the *UV* output, in the *Mapping* node tweak the *Location* and *Rotation* values, plug it into a *Texture > Gradient* node:

[image]

Comment: That is an cool way of looking doing this. Also add the mesh lines like the original image. Thanks a ton!